# Cypress afterHook does not wait for timeouts after failure

Tags: cypress, e2e

So, i have setup 2 customCommands for my Cypress setup `setupProject` and `removeProject`. Both click through the UI to create a Project, and to delete a Project. It also work as I expect it to. However the `removeProject` does only work, if no fail occurs in the tests.
If a fail happens, Cypress will not wait for timeouts or does not do clicks in the after hook. Therefore i have to do `cy.wait(4000)` and `.click({force: true})`

```
  // test.cy.ts
  before(() => cy.setupProject(PROJECT_NAME))
  after(() => cy.removeProject(PROJECT_NAME))
```

```
 // commands.ts (does work with no failure, but not with failure)
 Cypress.Commands.add('removeProject', (projectName: string) => {
  PROJECT_SELECTION_PAGE.visit()
  PROJECT_SELECTION_PAGE.getProjectDropdown().click()
  PROJECT_SELECTION_PAGE.getProjectOption(projectName).first().click()

  PROJECT_OVERVIEW_PAGE.DELETE.getButton().click()
  PROJECT_OVERVIEW_PAGE.DELETE.dialogIsVisible()
  PROJECT_OVERVIEW_PAGE.DELETE.getConfirmButton().click()
 })
```

```
 // commands.ts (does with failure and without)
 Cypress.Commands.add('removeProject', (projectName: string) => {
  PROJECT_SELECTION_PAGE.visit()
  cy.wait(4000)
  PROJECT_SELECTION_PAGE.getProjectDropdown().click({ force: true })
  cy.wait(4000)
  PROJECT_SELECTION_PAGE.getProjectOption(projectName).first().click({ force: true })
  cy.wait(4000)

  PROJECT_OVERVIEW_PAGE.DELETE.getButton().click({ force: true })
  cy.wait(4000)
  PROJECT_OVERVIEW_PAGE.DELETE.dialogIsVisible()
  cy.wait(4000)
  PROJECT_OVERVIEW_PAGE.DELETE.getConfirmButton().click({ force: true })
 })
```

What am I doing wrong with this? If I put the logic in a seperate `it('remove project')` it does work. But that would mean, I have to copy&paste this logic into every test...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a before hook for both.
First cleanup your state then set it up for a new test.

```
before(function () {
  cy.removeProject(PROJECT_NAME))
  cy.setupProject(PROJECT_NAME))
}
```